# App Engine Request Timeout for PubSub Push Subscription in Automatic Scaling

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

On App Engine in Automatic scaling on python2, request handlers had a max timeout of 60s for normal http requests and 10mins for Taskqueue requests.

I can't find any information about pubsub tasks. **Do they also get the 10 minute timeout like Taskqueue/cloud-tasks?**

Additionally it seems like google's changing their docs and in python3 all requests will have the 10 minute timeout:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-instances-are-managed

But if you go to their docs for cron in python3, it says `An HTTP request invoked by cron can run for up to 60 seconds` https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refer to a Pub/Sub task, I understand you mean having an App Engine service subscribe to topic as a Push subscriber.

According to the [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#push-subscription) documentation, what you would consider a “queue” is basically Pub/Sub dynamically adjusting the rate of push requests based on the rate at which it receives success responses.

With push subscriptions, Pub/Sub considers a HTTP success response as an acknowledgement of the worker receiving the message. However, you have to keep in mind that the deadline to provide this response is initially determined by the **ackDeadline** of the subscription, which is **10 seconds** by default, as mentioned in the [Managing Subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#manage_subs) documentation.

According to the [Receiving push messages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#receiving_push_messages) documentation, if the App Engine subscriber does not reply with a success HTTP status code within the ackDeadline, Pub/Sub will retry delivery until the message expires after the subscription's message retention period.

Conveniently, you can set the ackDeadline for the push subscription to a maximum of **10 minutes**, making it the same duration as the Python3 App Engine Standard with auto scaling deadline.

Regarding your question about the difference for the cron triggered requests, it is indeed how it is designed, but I would not be able to tell you why it is like that.

Also, for more information about the difference between Pub/Sub and Cloud Tasks you can refer to the official docs. Funnily enough, both [Cloud Task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/comp-pub-sub) and [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/tasks-vs-pubsub) docs contain a slightly different page talking about the different between the 2.

**EDIT:**

I decided to put the timeout deadline of Python2 apps to the test, and I confirmed that the limitation is indeed present even when receiving requests from a Pub/Sub push subscription.

I created 3 basic task handlers, that waited 80, 120, and 610 seconds to send a 200 http response respectively. When publishing to the topic, I noticed the following:

- As expected the service waiting for more than 10 minutes failed to acknowledge all the requests.
- The service waiting for 120s was successful in a few requests but failed in most of them.
- Strangely enough the service waiting for 80s successfully acknowledged all the requests.

This makes me believe the deadline for the Python2 is not such a hard limit as the documentation says. However, I still believe it is ideal to keep the documented deadline in mind when developing the apps, and be aware that, even for Pub/Sub tasks it will be somewhat applied.

As the runtime is most likely gonna be deprecated soon, I don’t think any changes in the documentation to specify the deadline for Pub/Sub tasks would be approved in time, as with Python3 there is no risk of App Engine terminating the request before the configured ackDeadline.

Comment: thanks for the note about `ackDeadline` since that too is important and is something i missed, but that doesnt alleviate the concern about App Engine potentially killing the request handler for a pub-sub subscription at the 60 second mark in Python2